# Crop Set of Images to Largest Area in Set

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photoshop-scripting

Pardon the title not making any sense.

I have a set of images (the total number of images varies), all square (i.e. usually 200 × 200 or 1000 × 1000)

They're sprites for a game, and I need to crop all images to the smallest possible area that still includes all pixels *but for all images*.

[image]

Let's say this image was originally 200 × 200, but when cropped down to only visible pixels, it's 140 × 100,

[image]

Let's say this image was originally 200 × 200, but when cropped down to only visible pixels, it's 100 × 140.

I want to crop both these images to 140 × 140, because that's the size that would not crop out any pixels in any image in the set.

> I have hundreds of sets of images so manually calculating it like the aforementioned isn't an option. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you familiar with photoshop scripting? It's quite trivial: get dimensions of all opened images or all images from a specific folder, select the largest on both sides, apply crop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Photoshop** there is a pretty straightforward way to do this.

Unfortunately this method adds a lot of noise to the filenames, but perhaps you can find a way to fix that afterwards.

First we'll gather the original images as layers in one document with the same document size as the largest of the images:

- Select *File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack*.
- Set *Source Files > Use* to *Folder*.
- Click the *Browse* button and locate the folder with the original files.
- Leave the two checkboxes unticked.
- Click *OK*.

Now we'll export all the layers trimmed to their smallest possible area:

- Select *File > Export > Layers to Files*.
- Click *Browse* to locate a folder you want to export to.
- Tick *Trim Layers*.
- Setup according to your needs.
- Click *Run* to save the files.
- Close the document. No need to save it.

Then we'll gather the trimmed images as layers in one document with the same document size as the largest of the images:

- Select *File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack*.
- Set *Source Files > Use* to *Folder*.
- Click the *Browse* button and locate the folder with the trimmed files.
- Leave the two checkboxes unticked.
- Click *OK*.

The images will be placed in top left corner of the document. If you want them to be centered you can do this:

- Select all layers in the *Layers* panel.
- Select the *Move Tool*.
- Click the *Align horizontal centers* in the top of the screen.
- Click the *Align vertical centers* in the top of the screen.

Finally we will export all the layers without trimming them:

- Select *File > Export > Layers to Files*.
- Click *Browse* to locate a folder you want to export to.
- Untick *Trim Layers*.
- Setup according to your needs.
- Click *Run* to save the files.
- Close the document. No need to save it.

Comment: Thank you! I can probably couple this with AutoHotKey or Photoshop's macro tools to take out some of the elbow grease. I've successfully staved off learning JavaScript... one more time

Comment: Code to do that would be about 5 times smaller than this message.. :))

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy, yes but posting code as an answer is a bit like posting a magic spell. People just grab the code, run it and never learn a thing from it. And really, performing this method doesn't take more than a minute (disregarding the process time). Just really tedious to describe. Copy/pasting your code might be quicker, but writing it yourself or actually *understanding* it would take way longer. But in this particular case a script *would* have the advantage that you would be able to completely customize the file naming.

Answer (score 0):

### With Gimp:

1. Open a first image
2. Use `File > Open as layers` to load the rest of the images in the set. You can select several images at once so you can load the whole set in one go.
3. `Image > Crop to content` crops the image to the smallest rectangle that contains all the non-transparent parts
4. Use a script to re-export all layers to individual files, like for instance [`ofn-export-layers`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible to do something with Photoshop CC: Use the new Select Subject functionality. Expand the selection by 1px. Then do Image > Crop.  You could record all this as an Action. Then apply the Action to a whole batch of PNGs using File > Automate > Batch.

The beauty of this is that it doesn't matter where the image is positioned in the original 200 x 200 image, as long as it's not too close to an edge. Also, no need to write any code.

Comment: But this this won't be able to figure out the largest bounding box to crop to?